Is there a Comprehensive US Election Candidate Dataset?
I'm trying to find a dataset for every single candidate contesting for any form of election (federal, state, local) in the US for the past 3-4 years for a political video ad classification project. Does anyone have any idea if this sort of database exists or how I can compile it? Just need name, party, state, and contested office.

"Contesting an election" can also mean standing in the election, not just objecting to its results. I believe it's the former definition (i.e. anyone who stood as a candidate in a US election) that OP is asking about here.

@F1Krazy: "contesting from any form of election" is not exactly idiomatic or perhaps even grammatical, so the Q needs a bit of copyediting/clarification.

There are lots of datasets available - see e.g. MIT. Do you really want everything: President, Congress, state legislature, local/city councillors/alderpeople/etc, elected judges, attorneys-general, police chiefs, sheriffs, DAs, mayors, licence collectors, other public officials...
